# How to add a Button-s in SWT?

Tags: java, layout, swt

Only one "frame" is displayed in the left corner,but I want (N * N) buttons in the display. I would like to create a table using SWT. The table will include a column with button(s).

```
private void createButtonPanel() {
    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.heightHint = N * imageSize;
    gridData.widthHint = N * imageSize;
    Composite buttonPanel = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    buttonPanel.setBackground(new Color(display, 140, 140, 100));
    buttonPanel.setLayoutData(gridData);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            button[i][j] = new Button(buttonPanel, SWT.PUSH);
            button[i][j].setSize(imageSize, imageSize);
            button[i][j].setImage(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I should change here?

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: The code is correct and in my programm i don't know why disfigure my panel :-?? . tnx for the answer !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use is

```
buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(N * imageSize, true));
```

This will create a `Layout` with `N * imageSize` equal-width columns. You don't have to define the number of rows explicitly.

No need to set `GridData#heightHint` and `GridData#widthHint` either.